# Pullback of $\mathcal Ext^i$ by the inclusion map

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective surface and $j:C \hookrightarrow X$ be a smooth projective irreducible curve on $X$. Let $F,G$ are two coherent sheaves on $C$. Then can we say that $j^{*} \mathcal{E}xt^i(F, G) \cong \mathcal{E}xt^{i}(j^{*} F, j^{*} G)$?.

I know that if the morphism is flat then this kind of isomorphism is there. Is inclusion $j$ flat? (Does it follow from the fact : "An immersion of (locally Noetherian) schemes is flat if and only if it is an open immersion, or a closed immersion of connected components." and the assumption that $C$ is irreducible? please correct me if this conclusion is wrong)

Any remark from anyone is welcome

Comment: Compute the example $F = G = i_*\mathcal{O}_C$.

Comment: @Sasha, this example gives us that the pullback is equal to $0$. Do you mean this is not true in general (Is this true for bundles?), then under what conditions we can restrict on curves and say $ \mathcal{E}xt^i(F, G)|_C \cong  \mathcal{E}xt^i(F|_C, G|_C)$?

Comment: The pullback is not zero.

Comment: @Sasha, I don't understand. If we take $F = G = i_*\mathcal{O}_C$, then $\mathcal{E}xt^{i}(i^{*} F, i^{*} G)$ is precisely $\mathcal{E}xt^{i}(\mathcal O_C, \mathcal O_C)$, this is $0$ if $i=1$ and equals to $\mathcal O_C$ if $i=0$. Here I'm using pullback of pushforward of a line bundle by inclusion is the line bundle itself

Comment: Your computation of the RHS is correct, so now you should compute the LHS in this example.

Comment: @Sasha, for $i=0$, L.H.S should be $O_C$. So for $i=0$ they do not match. What about $i=1$?.e.g. can we say something like the following is true: $\mathcal Ext^1(\mathcal O_C(C), \mathcal O_X)|_C \cong \mathcal Ext^1(\mathcal O_C(C), \mathcal O_C))?$

Comment: You seem to contradict to yourself.

Comment: @Sasha, I understand that the isomorphism in the original post is wrong by your example. Then how do we interpret those restrictions. Do you mean something else by "contradiction"?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking now.

Comment: @Sasha, For a precise example, let $L$ be  base point free on $C$. I was trying to show that $\mathcal Ext^1(\mathcal O_C(C) \otimes L^*, \mathcal O_X)|_C \cong L$. I do not see how to prove this without using the fact that restricting on $C$ means restricting both the components inside. That's why I asked the question. I was able to prove this using this fact( which you have pointed out to be wrong). Is there any other way to deduce that this restriction is precisely $L$.

Comment: Use a locally free resolution for $\mathcal{O}_C(C)$ to compute the local Ext, then restrict the result to $C$.